# How do I remove DbdocController?

Tags: grails, plugins, database-migration

I've installed Grails 2.1.2 and created a project.

When I run my project, the default page lists the following under Available Controllers:

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController
```

Not wanting to have to deal with this controller (which apparently doesn't work by default), I decided to try and get rid of it. Of course, the first thing I find is that there is no such controller under my project's `controllers` directory.

Having read that this controller is related to the database-migration plugin, I promptly uninstall this plugin using the `grails uninstall-plugin` command. This is successful according to Grails, but the controller is still there. The next thing I tried was to delete this plugin from my project's `plugins` directory, but I find that there is no such directory in my project.

How would I get rid of this virtual controller?

Comment: I would also like to add that compiling a Grails project with Java 1.8 or above can cause problems with this controller. What version of Java are you using? Also, what is the error that has you say "[this controller] doesn't work by default"? I got an error that said "Repetitive method name/signature" and it was because I was compiling with Java 1.8. I switched to Java 1.7 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need database migrations (this is unlikely) then you can uninstall the plugin by removing it from your `BuildConfig.groovy`. There's no other way to remove the controller. Note that it's disabled by default in prod, so there's no need to remove it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll enable it again once I know more about it, but for now I'm just doing simple tests in Grails to get to know it. Owning my controllers is just a part of that process.